# return interface by embedding type

Tags: go, struct, interface

I need to return an interface. But I get an error:

```
cannot use B literal (type B) as type K in return argument:
    B does not implement K (missing Check method)
```

I thought when I embed type I got all the methods of inner type and the interface type as well

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type K interface {
    Check()
}

type A struct {
    A string
}

type B struct {
    B A
}

func (a A) Check() {
    fmt.Println(a.A)
}

func newB(a A) K {
    return B{B: a}
}

func main() {
    a := A{A: "A struct"}
    b := newB(a)

    b.Check()

}
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is not embedding:

```
type B struct {
    B A
}
```

With the above, you have:

```
var b B
b.B.Check()
```

This is embedding:

```
type B struct {
  A
}
```

With the above, you have:

```
var b B
b.Check()
```

You also have:

```
b.A.Check()
```

Answer (score 0):

B has no Check method and nowhere in your sample code you do any embedding. Just have B implement Check. The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Take the Tour of Go once more and focus on „embedding.

Comment: I know that error says that I need to add method Check. I embedded A into B. But I want a possibility to return interface (K in this example) by obtaining method from A in B type.

Comment: so basically I need method of A type in B type and being type K without explicitly rewrite method to implement K interface.